# Trouble updating ControllerAdvice attribute more than one time

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I set up the following ControllerAdvice to check the current number of "Request" objects that belong to a certain user at any given time.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationAdvice {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationAdvice.class);

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Autowired
    RequestRepository requestRepository;

    @ModelAttribute("numRequests")
    public int numRequests(Principal principal, Model model) {
        Users user = usersRepository.findOneByInitialName(principal.getName());
        if (user != null) {
            log.info(user.getId().toString());

            // TODO Find all APPROVED requests if user is EMPLOYEE and all PENDING requests is user is MANAGER
            // TODO Reset to 0 once we hit /requests page
            // TODO Update this value on page refresh if not on /requests page
            for (RequestDO requestDO : requestRepository.findByUsersAndStatus(user, RequestStatus.PENDING)) {

                ArrayList<RequestDO> requestsList = new ArrayList<>();
                requestsList.add(requestDO);

                int numRequests = requestsList.size();
                log.info(String.valueOf(numRequests));
                model.addAttribute("numRequests", numRequests);
                return numRequests;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I pass the attribute "numRequests" to a fragment, "header" in my index template:

```
<body>

<div class="container" style="width: 100% !important;">

    <div th:replace="fragments/header :: header"></div>

    <div th:replace="fragments/null :: null"></div>

    <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"></div>

</div>

</body>
```

Inside the header.html fragment, I have a short `if statement` that displays the value of this attribute:

```
<th:block th:if="${numRequests} != '0'">
    <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">My Requests</div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden" class="circle">
        <th:block th:text="${numRequests}"></th:block>
    </div>
</th:block>
```

So this all works fine. If there are 0 request objects in the database, nothing shows. If there are more than 0, however, a circular notification badge appears and correctly shows the number 1. The problem is that no matter how many more request objects are created, I still always see the number 1. I'm sure that I'm querying for them correctly. Am I missing something fundamental here in terms of logic? Perhaps the attribute value is only ever updated once for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `requestsList` inside loop so per every iteration is created new empty `ArrayList` object and added one `RequestDO` object to it. You also have `return` statement inside loop, so function ends after first iteration. That's why you always receive 1 when there are requests in database and 0 when there aren't.

Basically the loop is needless. If there will be no further logic in that iterating over requests, you can discard the whole **for** loop:

```
@ModelAttribute("numRequests")
public int numRequests(Principal principal, Model model) {
    Users user = usersRepository.findOneByInitialName(principal.getName());
    if (user != null) {
        log.info(user.getId().toString());

        // TODO Find all APPROVED requests if user is EMPLOYEE and all PENDING requests is user is MANAGER
        // TODO Reset to 0 once we hit /requests page
        // TODO Update this value on page refresh if not on /requests page

        List<RequestDO> requestsList = requestRepository.findByUsersAndStatus(user, RequestStatus.PENDING);

        int numRequests = requestsList.size();
        log.info(String.valueOf(numRequests));
        model.addAttribute("numRequests", numRequests);
        return numRequests;
    }
    return 0;
}
```